# SwiftUI: List inside TabView inside NavigationView breaks animation

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to have a `TabView` inside a `NavigationView`. The reason is that I am showing a `List` inside the `TabView`. When a user taps on an item in the list, the list uses a `NavigationLink` to show a detailed screen.

The problem is that the `navigationBarTitle` is now broken. It does not animate when the user scrolls through the items (*sometimes*). I don't want to wrap my `NavigationView` inside the `TabView`, since that will always show the `TabView`. I don't want it.

This is the reproduction code. If you run this in the simulator, the animation will break when switch a few times between the tabs and you scroll through the list. You will see that the navigation bar will remain where it is, without the animation.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView {
                TestView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "person.3")
                    }
                TestView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "person.2")
                    }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Test")
            .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("test")
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is one of the exceptions to putting `NavigationView` first. You need to place `NavigationView` inside each of the tab items, or it will not work properly. You will then set the title and the style in each of the tab items.

Comment: @Yrb But when I do that, the TabView is always visible, I don't want that

Comment: If you want `TabView` to be a sub view in your app, you have to roll your own. Apple wrote it to be the wrapping view for all other views.

Comment: @Yrb You work with apple? I think it is a bug. It works perfectly as long as you don't switch tabs. As soon as you do that, it will break. That is weird

Comment: Apple hast provided a clean way to do this because they don't want it, it is in the guidelines. "Avoid hiding the tab bar when people navigate to different areas in your app. The tab bar is a global navigation control for your app, so make sure it’s always visible." -[Apple](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/bars/tab-bars/) This setup looks off on iPad, the title is never in the right spot when you add a navigation link/ master-detail view.

Comment: @loremipsum That is a good reference point but I am building a chat application and I want to hide my tab bar when the user enters a chat. I know zero chat applications which are showing the tab bar when chatting.

Comment: I don’t think I use any chat apps that have a tabview. Even less a chat app that is native and probably even less likely a chat app that is SwiftUI. But if I had to do it I would not use this setup I tried this on one of my apps and spent more time trying to make up for all the bugs. You should try something custom with navigation view. Little things will pop your views everywhere and as you incorporate iPad, watch, catalyst and/or macOS you will fight an uphill battle, there are workarounds like setting your navigation view to stack.

Comment: @loremipsum Alright thanks for the heads up. So you are saying: just go with Tabview -> NavigationView -> List, like Apple mentions? I will try that

Comment: That way is the “apple way”  per that link but you can do something with your own NavigationView, a switch for each “tab” and your own tab bar. Conditionally present the tabview/navigation view. There are other ways to bypass the issues. Just not a prebuilt way.

Comment: Note that literally none of this is documented in Apple's TabView docs.